# Elastic search range query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Consider 2 documents in an index as like below:

```
{
            "_index": "32",
            "_type": "places",
            "_id": "_FqlAzzSRN6Ge_294D5Mwg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name_3": "xxxx",
               "id_3": "xxxxx",
               "name_2": "xxxx",
               "id_2": "xxx",
               "name_1": "xxx",
               "id_1": "xxx",
               "tempid": "xxxxx",
               "field1": 316.6666666666667,
               "type": "processeddata"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "32",
            "_type": "places",
            "_id": "3RCO-zHeSr2nWFZd8W-MDg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name_3": "yyyy",
               "id_3": "yyy",
               "name_2": "yyy",
               "id_2": "yyy",
               "name_1": "yyyy",
               "id_1": "yyy",
               "tempid": "yy",
               "field2": 400.6666666666667,
               "type": "processeddata"
            }
         }
```

I want to construct a query for the following scenario. I have to find the documents for field in particular range.

field1:200-400
field2:300-400 so the above 2 documents should come.

My query is as follows:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "field1": {
              "gte": 200,
              "lte": 400
            }
          },"range": {
            "field2": {
              "gte": 300,
              "lte": 400
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But the above query "Looks for 2 fields in a singe document, so no result is coming. SO i have to make to search if any of the filed satisfies the range in the document should return. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bool should` and not `bool must`. That would mean match any document that matches at least one condition. 
NOTE: Your second condition won't match second document as 400.66 does not fall in the range `[300, 400]`.